# DTM to GeoTIFF using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I need a GeoTIFF for HEC-RAS but only have a DTM exported from OpenRoads Microstation. Is there a way with QGIS to load in a DTM and then export a GeoTIFF?
I have QGIS version 3.22.10 and cannot get LAStools to work for me.

Comment: You says you have a DTM but don't specify format, is that a raster DTM (That some would call a DEM) or a vector DTM (3D points) ?

Answer (score 0):

Import your DTM, edit the symbology, and then export to geotiff via "Convert map to raster" from the Processing Toolbox.